# run into an exception when try to add/delete rules in runtime for drools

Tags: drools

Hi I am using drools in my spring-boot project using Drools 7.55.0.Final jar.

I tried to insert/update rules in runtime for drools using `org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl#addPackages`, and also use `org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl#removeRule` to remove rule.

It works fine usually. But sometimes it can run into an exception that shows below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: ConditionalBranchNode cannot be shared
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ConditionalBranchNode.doRemove(ConditionalBranchNode.java:265) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.common.BaseNode.remove(BaseNode.java:150) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removeLeftTupleNode(ReteooBuilder.java:247) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removePath(ReteooBuilder.java:225) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removeNodes(ReteooBuilder.java:203) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removeTerminalNode(ReteooBuilder.java:196) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.reteoo.ReteooBuilder.removeRules(ReteooBuilder.java:177) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.internalRemoveRules(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:1575) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.lambda$removeRules$7(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:1568) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.enqueueModification(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:748) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.removeRules(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:1568) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.mergePackage(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:1309) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.internalAddPackages(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:912) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.lambda$addPackages$2(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:731) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.enqueueModification(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:748) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
    at org.drools.core.impl.KnowledgeBaseImpl.addPackages(KnowledgeBaseImpl.java:731) ~[drools-core-7.55.0.Final.jar!/:7.55.0.Final]
```

It isn't always happening that's why I can't find the root cause. Has anyone has come across this before? How can I deal with this?
As Roddy suggested,below is the code for adding/updating

```
KnowledgeBuilder kb = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder();
        kb.add(ResourceFactory.newByteArrayResource(content.getBytes()), ResourceType.DRL);

        KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kb.getErrors();
        if (!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(errors)) {
            for (KnowledgeBuilderError error : errors) {
                log.error(error.toString());
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("load rules error");
        }
        InternalKnowledgeBase kBase = (InternalKnowledgeBase) kieBase;
        kBase.addPackages(kb.getKnowledgePackages());
```

for removing just use

```
        kieBase.removeRule("rules", name);
```

and I trigger those two actions with an interface which will transfer the rules to my system.
Rules can be used at the same time by calling "kieSession.fireAllRules()".
I think this is okay?I remember there should be locks while doing updating/deleting.

Comment: and after this exception occurred,some rules in memory did not work

Comment: I think it's related to the rules you are trying to add/update into kieseesion, cant really tell without looking at what rule you have

Comment: @ArjunPunnam hi there is the rule I tried to update.rule "63ababce71c2b0e4eecfcd0c"
    agenda-group "xxx"
    salience 1
when

    $data : Map(  )

    $her : Map(  ) from $data.getOrDefault("her",new HashMap());

    $cr : Map(  ) from $data.getOrDefault("cr",new HashMap());
    if ( $her.getOrDefault("team","").toString().contains("s")||Objects.equals($cr.getOrDefault("mu","").toString(),"Mutual Fund Only") )  break[a0]

    List( size()<0 )
then
then[a0] //do something;

end

Comment: that rule is already existed and works fine so the rule itself is fine I think.I tried to update some value in it and then met that exception.

Comment: Please share the code where you're changing the rules. Also explain how you're triggering it -- eg. are you guaranteeing nothing is using the rules at the same time to avoid concurrent modification issues (which is what it looks like you're hitting.)

Comment: Please modify your question with the 'edit' link with the additional information instead of putting it in the comments.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas thanks for the kind remind.I've added some explain.And you think applying the rules and changing the rules in the same time can cause this issue? Should I put some locks then?

Comment: The stack trace makes me think that you might have a concurrent modification issue, based on the fact that you're failing to remove a node and getting a 'cannot be shared' message -- the node _is_ shared because something is currently using it (eg executing rules, possibly.) It would also explain why the issue is intermittent.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using building/updating using **internal-** APIs (i.e.: `InternalKnowledgeBase#addPackages`) you should consider standard mechanism to instantiate/run/upgrade the KJAR per usual KJAR upgrade paradigm.

E.g. using a Kie Scanner

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
ReleaseId releaseId = kieServices
  .newReleaseId("com.sample", "my-app", "1.0-SNAPSHOT");
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.newKieContainer(releaseId);
KieScanner kScanner = kieServices.newKieScanner(kContainer);

// Start KIE scanner for polling the Maven repository every 10 seconds (10000 ms)
kScanner.start(10000L);
```

from: https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#kie-scanner-proc_packaging-deploying

E.g. programmatically invoking update of KieContainer

```
kieContainer.updateToVersion( <newReleaseId> );
```

from: https://docs.drools.org/7.73.0.Final/kie-api-javadoc/org/kie/api/runtime/KieContainer.html#updateToVersion(org.kie.api.builder.ReleaseId)

Comment: Hi, @tarilabs would this approach work inside a docker container?